# UIPopover presenting modal view controller, need notification of it's dismissal

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have an iPad app where I present a UIPopoverController form the right bar button item in my navigation controller.  When an item is selected in the popover it displays a modal view controller.  I need notification in my main viewcontroller that this modal view controller called by my UIPopoverController was dismissed.

I was hoping a simple viewWillShow would work but it is not fired.  Do I have to do some nested type of delegation?  Where I have my dismissed modal notify my popover and then that pass it along down the line?  Was hoping for some simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the view controller which displays the popover the delegate of the popover and implement this method (see UIPopoverControllerDelegate protocol):

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    // Do what you need here and release the popover ivar if you don't need it any more
    [myPopoverController release];
    myPopoverController = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't this be `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewWillShow`?
but anyway, you can use a delegate or `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`